# How can I sort a set of fixed length records within a byte array in golang

Tags: go

I am reading a series of bytes from a file into a byte array.  The file is many GBs so I will be reading it in chunks and merging them after the chunks are sorted are sorted.  I am trying to figure out how to sort these fixed length records.  The sort swap method will be swapping 99 bytes.  So something like this

```
var _bytes []byte
_bytes = make([]byte, 99*10)   // read 10 records

bufr := bufio.NewReader(fd)
bufr.Read(_bytes)

// then attempt to sort

type sortrecs[]byte

func (s sortrecs) Swap(i, j int) {
tmp := make([]byte, 99)
copy(tmp, s[i])   // Probably I will need to multiple i and j by 99
copy(s[i:], s[j])
copy(s[j:], tmp)
}
```

I tried messing with multipling i and j by the record length but i and j are not enumerating correctly.  I tried a simple 10 record file and I would expect i and j to range from 0 to 9.

I tried:

```
func (s sortrecs) Len() int {
return 99
}
```

The comparison method needs to compare just the 1st 20 bytes.  The record itself is fixed length and contains binary data mostly and some string data.

I tried a number of methods by not having any luck.  all the examples sort structures, strings or single integers.  None that I could find that sort fixed length records in place.  I could convert to structures and sort, which I tried but it was way too slow.  It worked fine in the MB range but 10's of GBs not so much.  I want to sort in place if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're not that far off, you just need to take a step back and think things through.

Starting with Len:

```
func (s sortrecs) Len() int {
    return len(s) / 99
}
```

You want to return the number of records. Since each record occupies 99 bytes in the slice, you need to divide the len of the slice by 99.

Then Swap:

```
func (s sortrecs) Swap(i, j int) {
    var tmp [99]byte
    ii := i*99
    jj := j*99
    copy(tmp[:], s[ii:ii+99])
    copy(s[ii:ii+99], s[jj:jj+99])
    copy(s[jj:jj+99], tmp)
}
```

You had exactly the right idea, only you didn't *do* it. Compute the starting indices in the slice by multiplying by 99, and swap 99 bytes starting at each index using a temporary buffer.

And finally Less:

```
func (s sortrecs) Less (i, j int) bool {
    ii := i*99
    jj := j*99
    return bytes.Compare(s[ii:ii+20], s[jj:jj+20]) < 0
}
```

`bytes.Compare` does the work for us. Compute the starting indices the same way `Swap` does, but only peek at the first 20 bytes. `Compare` returns -1 if its first argument is less than its second, 0 if they're equal, and 1 if the first argument is greater, so to implement `Less` we only need to find the -1 case.

Finally, it's probably a good idea to write a helper function for the "type conversion":

```
func NewSortRecs(b []byte) (sortrecs, error) {
    if len(b) % 99 != 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("slice length %d isn't a multiple of 99", len(b))
    }
    return sortrecs(b), nil
}
```

to prevent any unexpected behavior on invalid input, since the rest of the code is built around the assumption that the length will be a multiple of 99.

Answer (score 1):

Right that was my mistake.  I thought the Len() was the size of the structure when in fact it was record count.  I got it working.  Posting here.  Any comments or improvements are greatly appreciated.

```
const reclen = 99
const maxChunkRecords = 10

type sortRecords []byte

func (s sortRecords) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return bytes.Compare(s[i*reclen:i*reclen+20], s[j*reclen:j*reclen+20]) == -1
}

func (s sortRecords) Swap(i, j int) {
    tmp := make([]byte, reclen)
    copy(tmp, s[i*reclen:i*reclen+reclen])
    copy(s[i*reclen:], s[j*reclen:j*reclen+reclen])
    copy(s[j*reclen:], tmp)
}

func (s sortRecords) Len() int {
    return maxChunkRecords
}

func sortFixedLengthRecords(sFileName string) {
    
    _bytes := make([]byte, reclen*maxChunkRecords)

    fd, _ := os.Open(sFileName)
    bufr := bufio.NewReader(fd)
    bufr.Read(_bytes)
    fd.Close()
    sort.Sort(sortRecords(_bytes))
}
```